# Cumulative Sum of week sales

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum

```
SELECT 
   WeeklyReportDetailsDataId, ItemId, StoreId, 
   ManufacturerRetailerAssocId, WeekSales, WKYR,
   SUM(WeekSales) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId, StoreId, ManufacturerRetailerAssocId 
                        ORDER BY ItemId, StoreId, ManufacturerRetailerAssocId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROWS) as ytd 
FROM 
   WeeklyReportDetailsData   
WHERE 
   ManufacturerRetailerAssocId = 10 
GROUP BY
   ItemId, StoreId, WeekSales, WeeklyReportDetailsDataId, WKYR, 
   ManufacturerRetailerAssocId  
ORDER BY 
   WeeklyReportDetailsDataId, ItemId, StoreId, ManufacturerRetailerAssocId, WKYR
```

I am getting error that incorrect syntax near ROWS  Please help!!!!!!

Comment: ***WHAT DATABASE*** and which exact version are you running this against?

Comment: i am using Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 enterprise verison .

Comment: give your table structure script

Answer (score 0):

Change `CURRENT ROWS` to `CURRENT ROW`.  That should solve your error!

**EDIT:**

Your comment mentioning that you're on 2008 R2 indicates that you do not have the ability to use the "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED....." part.

Please see the difference between the `OVER()` aggregate function for SQL server [2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)